# How to iterate through all the bootstrap tabs and print contents on a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How to iterate through all the bootstrap tabs and print contents  (not only the one for the active tag , but the inactive ones too) on click of a `Print` button present in any of the tabs .
***Each tab has dynamically inserted content***. Tried some suggested css changes I found in related SO solutions. Those did not work for me.

`onclick` function for my print button is here

```js
function printMe() {
  var theWork = window.open('', 'PrintWindow');
  var tabs_html = "<html><head><title>Print</title>";
  tabs_html += "<style>body { padding: 15px; }</style></head>";
  $(".tabs").each(function() {
    $(this).find(".nav-tabs li").each(function(index, element) {
      tabs_html += "<h2>" + $(this).text() + "</h2><br/>";
      tabs_html += $(".tab-content .tab-pane").eq(index).html() + "<br/><br/>";
    });
    $(this).after(tabs_html + "</body></html>");
  });
    theWork.document.open();
    theWork.document.write(tabs_html);
    theWork.document.close();
    theWork.print();
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7WuNf/821/)**

Comment: First of all, you are trying to print for each .tabs item. I think it should be outside your .each function.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7WuNf/821/     simple code with the tabs and the function  I use in the code.

Comment: Please complete your fiddle since there are no items with class 'tabs' or '".nav-tabs li"'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

1. You are appending the closing `body` and `html` tags inside the `each` loop.
2. You are selecting the elements with the class `tabs`. But there seems to be no such element in the provided DOM/ Fiddle.

I have fixed the above two issues by 1. Moving the closing `body` and `html` tags out of the loop, and 2. Replacing the `.class` selector with an `#id` selector, and voila! it works.

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/MohdAbdulMujib/pen/OXxGBg)